# Is Child Category can have multiple parent categories..?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a requirement to make one category that is child for multiple parent categories, below sketch will explained more:

```
   ---------        ----------
   |CATEGORY|       |CATEGORY|
   ---------        ----------
       |________________|
                 |
            ----------
            |CATEGORY|
            ----------
```

I find several extension but they all work for items to multiple categories, is there any way to do that or any extension that allow us to do this, kindly need experts guidance.

Comment: I go with the Tags option...as their is menu link for the tags, so i am giving the same tags to those items those lie on the same category...so this way i can view them on single page

Answer (score 0):

I think that you intend to do this for the (main-)menu and not for article-categories?

It's not possible to link to a menu twice because a menu entry need a parent.

But you can do the following (its more like a workaround) and create:

```
-Cat1
 --Cat1.1
-Cat2
 --Cat2.1
```

If the Cat1.1 is the category you want to point to, you can choose the Cat2.1. and select "Alias" for the "Menu Item Type". Now you can choose Cat1.1 from the list and you are finish. Now you have created a submenu which points to a different category in your system.